# Practical limit on optimization tending to negative infinity

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, machine-precision

Consider $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$
$$f(\mathbf x):=\sum_i{e^{x_i}}$$
The gradient of $f(\mathbf x)$ is the function itself. Notably, the gradient magnitude decreases exponentially, if the goal is to minimize $f(\mathbf x)$. In that case, the theoretical minimum tends to $-\infty$.

It would appear that for functions, where the minima tend to $-\infty$, ignoring other factors such as the stopping criterion, learning rate, and time, the practical limit of where $\mathbf x$ will end up eventually is only limited by the hardware precision, i.e, a very small negative number but not $-\infty$.

Additionally, if $\nabla_{\mathbf x}f(\mathbf x)$ decreases exponentially, then can such a practical "convergence" be expected to happen quickly (as in relation to $-\infty$) in practice subject to the learning rate and the stopping criterion (because the gradient vanishes)?

I suspect this might be a trivial question but I couldn't find a definite answer. Is there anything else to consider in such cases?

Also, the properties of $f(\mathbf x)$ at this practical finite value might be significantly different from its theoretical properties at $-\infty$. In such cases, the experiments might not give the expected results. So would it make any sense to study $f(\mathbf x)$ as $\mathbf x\to \mathbf k$ for some very small finite negative number $k$ such that $\mathbf k= [k, ..., k]$?

Comment: PS: ChatGPT thinks I am right, but I don't trust it, even more so for mathematical matters.

Comment: In my experience, ChatGPT tends to agree with you on pretty much everything related to maths. If you point out an error, it just says "Sorry for the confusion, you're right." And then again.

Comment: The minimum of $f(\mathbf{x})$ cannot tend to $-\infty$, since $f \geq 0$.

Comment: $f(x)\to 0\implies x\to -\infty$